# how should i check stability of community detection algorithm?

Tags: r, graphs

I have a community detection algorithm that communities can't have overlap. It works based on density of edges. Now I want to see how stable this algorithm is (if I decrease internal edges and increase edges between communities). Is there a standard way to do it?